# Custom Collection View

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdelegate

I have implemented the custom collection view using storyboard. and added a cross button and background image.

When collection view reloading that cross button have been hide for admin and shown for other members which is work perfectly first time.

I have set the tag btn.tag = indexpath.row and assign a function for remove user.

After removing the user and remove the object from the Array when reloading the collection view now that condition I have added for admin to hide button is not working and cross button displayed in all the cells of collection view.

Please anyone help.

```
        if ([user.type isEqualToString:@"admin"])

        {        [removeBtn setHidden:YES];

                [removeBtn setEnabled:NO];

        }else {

     [removeBtn setHidden:NO];

        [removeBtn setEnabled:YES]; }
```

Firsttime reloading the collection view result

[image]

After Remove Member reloading the collection view result
[image]

Debug Log After Press Remove Button but cross is now displayed in Admin Item Image.

```
2016-02-03 11:35:03.620 STT[32132:5629002] Col View 2usertype>    admin
2016-02-03 11:35:03.620 STT[32132:5629002] Hide cross from Admin
2016-02-03 11:35:12.944 STT[32132:5629002] Col View 2usertype>   
2016-02-03 11:35:12.944 STT[32132:5629002] Show cross for Mem
2016-02-03 11:35:17.799 STT[32132:5629002] Col View 2usertype>   member
2016-02-03 11:35:17.800 STT[32132:5629002] Show cross for Mem
```

Comment: can you please share  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution after removing this line (remove.tag=indexPath.row) its working.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.
//Register class

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCellIdentifier"];
```

at `cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

// Setup cell identifier

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: CustomCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
  User *objUser = [self.UserArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  [cell updateCellData:objUser]; // set tag here and hide/show + button
```

Comment: I have already used UICollectionViewCell *objCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: please debug and check that if ([user.type isEqualToString:@"admin"]) its correct.

Comment: I have checked its correct value is admin see the log updated in question